# Can't find LineGraphView, GraphViewSeries, GraphViewData

Tags: android-graphview

I'm starting to work with GraphView 4.2.2. I found some examples that use the following imports:

```
import com.jjoe64.graphview.GraphView.GraphViewData;
import com.jjoe64.graphview.GraphViewSeries;
import com.jjoe64.graphview.LineGraphView;
```

However, in my implementation (gradle 4.7, sdk 27), the symbols can't be resolved.
What am I missing? Are these classes no longer supported in GraphView 4.2.2. ?
Do I need to downgrade?

Answer (score 0):

Add this line into the `dependencies` block of the "build.gradle" file under your `app` directory :

```
implementation 'com.jjoe64:graphview:4.2.2'
```

Comment: I did add the implementation 'com.jjoe64:graphview:4.2.2' under dependencies in buildgradle(module app) but the imports LineGraphView and GraphViewSeries appear erroneous, However if I change to implementation 'com.jjoe64:graphview:3.1.4' then the errors go away. Why do I need to downgrade?